# JAXB vs Apache XMLBeans

Tags: java, xml, apache

Anyone can tell me which one is better (JAXB or Apache XMLBeans) taking in account the performance for files bigger than 10Mb?

Comment: **As a side note to developers:**  currently XMLBeans project is officially retired and active development is ceased. Pay attention to the message on top of the Apache XMLBeans [home page](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) (quote): _"2014/05/23 - Apache XMLBeans has been **retired**. For more information, please explore the [Apache Attic](http://attic.apache.org/projects/xmlbeans.html)."_

Comment: XMLBeans came back from attic it seams... `Project Apache XMLBeans was in the Attic from July 2013 until June 2018.`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both have similar performances, however even if Apache XMLBeans seems to present better performance, I normally choose JAXB because I don't want to increase the size of my applications with 3rd party tools.

With Apache XMLBeans you need a small package around 2mb, it's probably easy to learn and well documented. Have full support of XSD specification and namespaces, and mapping only via XML Schema Definition (XSD). It also seems to use deprecated API’s.

Comment: I'm trying to create a webstart application so the size of the final application is very important and probably the heaviest factor in my decision since the difference in performance is not too big.

Answer (score 8):

The architect of XmlBeans wrote about why he chose to build XmlBeans, even though JAXB was the established standard.  Take a look at his [blog](http://davidbau.com/mt/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=1&search=xmlbeans), specifically the [problems with jaxb](http://davidbau.com/archives/2003/11/25/jaxb_problems.html) The most compelling advantage was type substitution.

Comment: The `problems with jaxb` blog post is in reference to JAXB 1 (JSR-31).  JAXB 2 (JSR-222) is leaps and bounds better.  This is due in part to contributions made by David Bau who was a member of the JAXB 2 expert group.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer XMLBeans, because it comes with a handy tool called "inst2xsd" which allows you to generate an XML schema from an XML instance document. JAXB is not able to do this.

See http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#inst2xsd

Comment: JAXB 2 can generate XML Schemas, see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#generateSchema(javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver)

Comment: JAXB 2 cannot generate schema from xml. The schemagen tool only generates schema from java classes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212064/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-xsd-from-a-jaxb-annotated-class :)

Comment: @everlasto: As Kamran pointed out, the comment is about generation from XML instance files.

Answer (score 1):

agree with bruno. JAXB is bundled with Java for a reason

Comment: No, because it won the xml-java-object-mapping-tool lottery :)

Comment: JAXB is not a tool but a spec (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222).  The Metro JAXB impl (https://jaxb.dev.java.net/) is included in Java SE 6.  There are other JAXB impls such as MOXy (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and JaxMe (http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/).

Comment: its removed since JDK11