# Is it possible to generate a XSD from a JAXB-annotated class?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I've written a number of classes using JAXB for serialization and I was wondering if there was a way to generate a XSD file for each of these objects based on the annotations. Is there a tool for this?

Something like `generate-xsd com/my/package/model/Unit.java` would be *awesome*. Does anything exist to do this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `generateSchema` method on JAXBContext:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
SchemaOutputResolver sor = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);
```

You leverage an implementation of `SchemaOutputResolver` to control where the output goes:

```
public class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {

    public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(suggestedFileName);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        result.setSystemId(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, see the Maven plugin for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251458/generating-xsd-schemas-from-jaxb-types-in-maven

Comment: Hi, this method does nothing for me (`createOutput` never called). I'm using this implementation: `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl`. Any thoughts? - Thanks

Comment: Yep, tried both breakpoint and *System.err.print*. I'm creating the context from package name using `jaxb.index` file. My context works well otherwise (it marshalls object graphs without any problem).

Comment: It is caused by implementing an interface on one of the JAXB annotated classes. It is strange because the interface only contains one method (a getter) and it is not related to a JAXB property. - **So the example is excellent, no additional magic is required**, but the schema generator is much more picky than the marshaller.

Comment: I think it'd be better to use 
`result.setSystemId(file.getAbsolutePath());`
instead of `result.setSystemId(file.toURI().toURL().toString());`
I had a file not found exception when use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the answer a bit so we can pass our class and also get the `path` where XSD file has been created:

```
public class SchemaGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        SchemaOutputResolver sor = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
        jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);
    }
}

class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {
    @SneakyThrows
    public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName) {
        File file = new File(suggestedFileName);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        result.setSystemId(file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        return result;
    }
}
```