# How to generate an XML schema file from (JAXB) annotated Java classes, using JDK8

Tags: jaxb, java-8

The instructions to generate schema through running "schenagen" as suggested in Java API documentation worked with JDK7, but not with JDK8.

Here is the documentation page:
http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxb/index.html

Here is the line from this page with links to the instructions:

"
Running the schema generator (schemagen): [[command-line instructions](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/schemagen.html), [using the SchemaGen Ant task]](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/schemagenTask.html)

"

Schema generator does not work because some classes have been removed from JDK8:
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory"

There is another solution suggested here:
[Generating XSD schemas from JAXB types in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251458/generating-xsd-schemas-from-jaxb-types-in-maven)

This solution also works with JDK7 but not with JDK8; it will end up with a similar error:

"Class not foundcom/sun/tools/apt/Main.class"

The root cause is probably the same: the annotation processing tools are removed from JDK8.
This change was planned in JEP 117 long time ago:
http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/117

How can I generate an XML schema file from (JAXB) annotated Java classes now, using JDK8?

Comment: I am asking the same at this OTN thread: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3536370

Comment: I am researching alternatives to JAXB: http://www.springfuse.com/2009/10/01/why-we-switched-from-jabx-to-jibx.html

Comment: I have found the solution based on Marco's suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This was a bug in the "jaxb2-maven-plugin". You must use the version 1.6 or later of the plugin

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schemagen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/projectname/model/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/schemas</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Using version 2.2 I could make schemagen is working. The suggested 1.6 version printed message that sources are not changed, skipping schema generation.

Comment: Yes , using 1.6 worked. ( Seems 1.5 is not working with Java 8 ).Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `generateSchema` method on `JAXBContext` to generate an XML Schema:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#generateSchema%28javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver%29

Comment: This path looks promising even with JDK8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html . Any suggestions how to call this method in a Maven pom file? Is there a Maven plugin which is based on calling this method and not using APT?