# XML Data modeling tools

Tags: xml, data-modeling

I want to create model classes from XML that I have written for my Java application. 
What are some good tools to convert auto generated classes from the XML I am writing ?
A sample from my XML file.

```
  <list name="NameValuePairListDefinition">
    <member target="NameValuePair" />
  </list>

  <structure name="PositiveIntegerList">
    <member name="list" target="PositiveIntegerListDefinition" />
  </structure>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with Java and want to generate classes I would highly suggest going with [XMLbeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/). It comes with some nice utilities, including:

- **inst2xsd** : given the xml , it generates xsd

  EXAMPLE

  `inst2xsd -enumerations never message.xml`

  (will generate xsd file and disable any enumerations of identical type)
- **scomp** : compiles the schema into a *jar* file, which means it generates a pretty nice reusable library for you which contains a class (or multiple classes) based on the namespace of the schema (or starting with *noNamespace.something*) if you didn't define any in your XML

  EXAMPLE

  `scomp -jar yourschema mySchema.xsd`

  (which creates **xmltypes.jar** - which is the jar you want, just rename it to something clever and use it for two-way parsing for getting & setting, reading & writing values)
- lastly, just launch your java IDE  and add all the xmlbeans JARS and JAR for your schema created by *scomp*

You can then load,create,store,manipulate, with your xmldata as it would just be java objects in your projects ;-)

Based on the  Element of your small XML snippet, you'd be accessing with code that looks roughly as follows:

```
 MyModel myModel = null;
 try {
    //full path to XML file
    File modelXML = new File("Model.xml");

    // Bind the incoming XML to an XMLBeans type.
    myModel = MyModel.Factory.parse(modelXML);
 } 
 catch (XmlException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
 catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
 catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace();  }

 // Using the <structure> element.
 Structure structure = myModel.getStructure();
 Member member = structure.getMember();
 String target = member.getTarget(); // "PositiveIntegerListDefinition"
```

NOTE: Something I'd also suggest is using Element names that are not reserved Java keywords such as *list*, I'm not exactly sure how XMLBeans will handle it but I'm assuming it would either rename it slightly rather than overload.

Here's a full tutorial which could come in handy:
http://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/tutorial_getstarted.html

I made the assumption you are using simple direct XML calling or REST-based Web Services, but if you decided to use something more verbose like SOAP there are also [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and [Apache Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) which can easily generate Java classes from SOAP XML messages or WSDLs.

Comment: this answers my question. I think I am going to go with XMLBeans. More googling tells me there is also JAXB 2, wondering which is better.

Comment: Seems a discussion/question around this already happened too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362030/jaxb-vs-apache-xmlbeans
Some prefer JAXB 2 because it is native Java but some still find use for XMLBeans for some minor performance improvements and additional features, its really a matter of personal preference of whether you think its worth using an external 3rd party library or not. If I had a small personal project I would almost always use XMLBeans, but if it was a larger complex enterprise one I might think twice before adding dependencies and just stick with JAXB.